# how to update database table each time csv file get uploaded in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

**my csv file looks like:**
[image: sv file]

**my database table looks like:**
[image]

my need is that each time I am uploading the csv file i need to update the database table, I mean if the **mid** in csv file is present in database **mid** I have to update that row. And if **mid** in csv file is not present in database **mid** I have to insert that new row to the database table.

currently I upload the csv file and data stored in database table successfully.

**my controller looks like:**

```
public function importcsv() 
{

    $data['menu'] = $this->AdminModel->get_menu();
    $data['error'] = '';    //initialize image upload error array to empty

    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);


    // If upload failed, display error
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) 
    {
        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

        $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $file_data = $this->upload->data();
        $file_path =  './assets/uploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];

        if ($this->csvimport->get_array($file_path)) 
        {

            $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_path);
            foreach ($csv_array as $row) 
            {

                $mid=$row['mid'];

                $insert_data = array(
                    'mid'=>$mid,
                    'category'=>$row['category'],
                    'name'=>$row['name'],
                    'price'=>$row['price'],
                    'description'=>$row['description'],
                );
             $this->AdminModel->insert_csv($insert_data);

        }

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Csv Data Imported Succesfully');
            redirect(base_url().'Admin/menu');

        } 
        else 
            $data['error'] = "Error occured";
            $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
        }

    }
```

I think after fetching the **csv** file data into the array **$insert_data** I think I need to compare it with the **mid** in the database table. How is it possible? I am new to this. thanking in advance.

***I made modifications in my controller, its looks:***

```
public function importcsv() 
{

    $data['menu'] = $this->AdminModel->get_menu();
    $data['error'] = '';    //initialize image upload error array to empty

    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);


    // If upload failed, display error
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) 
    {
        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

        $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $file_data = $this->upload->data();
        $file_path =  './assets/uploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];

        if ($this->csvimport->get_array($file_path)) 
        {

            $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_path);
            foreach ($csv_array as $row) 
            {


                $data1['mid']=$row['mid'];
                $data1['category']=$row['category'];
                $data1['name']=$row['name'];
                $data1['price']=$row['price'];
                $data1['description']=$row['description'];


                    if($this->db->where('mid', $data1['mid']))
                    {

                         $this->db->update('menu', $data1);
                    }
                    if($this->db->where("mid !=",$data1['mid']))
                    {


                        $this->db->insert('menu', $data1);

                    }

            }        

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Csv Data Imported Succesfully');
            redirect(base_url().'Admin/menu');

        } 
        else 
        {
            $data['error'] = "Error occured";
            $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
        }

    }
}
```

Now I can update data By

```
if($this->db->where('mid', $data1['mid']))
{
    $this->db->update('menu', $data1);
 }
```

its works fine, but using condition:

```
if($this->db->where("mid !=",$data1['mid']))
{
    $this->db->insert('menu', $data1);
}
```

the whole csv file data is reentered into the table menu. I need to compare  **mid** in the **menu** table and **mid** in the csv file, if **mid** in the **csv file** not present in  **menu** table, I need to insert that corresponding record into the **menu** table.

for that what all changes should I have to done in the code?

Comment: is `mid` unique then?

Comment: before inserting a record , you can check whether same mid exists or not. If exist update else insert. You can do this with  a single sql query

Comment: you should make it a unique key in the DB then you can use `insertOnDuplicate`

Comment: @Anish I try a lot but, not working yet Can u add the query to check the condition.

Comment: for update you will compare the records one by one. if there are not a lot of records the best way is delete all of them and insert again. (maybe the primary key value will change).

Comment: @phper yes I already done using that logic, but as per my requirement I have to compare each record, i am still working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution. Thank u all for your support and time.

```
public function importcsv() 
{

    $data['menu'] = $this->AdminModel->get_menu();
    $data['error'] = '';    //initialize image upload error array to empty

    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);


    // If upload failed, display error
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

        $this->load->view('admin/csvindex', $data);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $file_data = $this->upload->data();
        $file_path =  './assets/uploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];

        if ($this->csvimport->get_array($file_path)) 
        {

            $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_path);
            foreach ($csv_array as $row) 
            {


                $data1['mid']=$row['mid'];
                $data1['category']=$row['category'];
                $data1['name']=$row['name'];
                $data1['price']=$row['price'];
                $data1['description']=$row['description'];


                    $this->db->where('mid', $data1['mid']);
                    $q= $this->db->get('menu');
                    if( $q->num_rows() > 0 )
                    {
                        $this->db->where('mid',$data1['mid']); 
                        $this->db->update('menu',$data1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->db->set('mid',$data1['mid']);
                        $this->db->insert('menu', $data1);
                    }                 
            } 

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Csv Data Imported Succesfully');
            redirect(base_url().'Admin/menu');

        } 
        else 
        {
            $data['error'] = "Error occured";
            $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Logic:**
If data is already there in the database. Then you have to compare database field with CSV field. If both are matching then update data else insert data.

Thanks